# If $\mu$ is a measure, the the collection of all $\mu$-measurable sets is a $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, metric-spaces

I'm studying from "Topics on Analysis in metric spaces" by Ambrosio Luigi and Paolo Tilli. The Theorem $1.1.6$ is the theorem written in the title. The passage that i don't understand is the last one: [image]

where the proof is the follow:

[image]

I understand that the first two terms in the second line are from splitting the union of the first term, and the third term of the second line came from that $F \cap (\cup_i A_i)^c \subseteq F \cap (\bigcup_i^{n}A_i)^c$ and for subadditivity of $\mu$. Such that the finite union is measurable we obtaion $\mu(F)$ in the third line and also for subadditivity we have the series in the fourth line.

The last part is the follow:

[image]

Why "it suffices to prove that the series is convergent"?. If the series converges to a $k$ constant I don't obtain the disequality in the first picture but I obtain "$\leq \mu(F)+k$".
Could someone please help me?
Thanks

NB: $A_i$s are pairwise disjoint.

Comment: Do you mean „If mu is an outer measure“?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the series is convergent, then for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ for which
$$\sum_{i>n}\mu(F\cap A_i)<\varepsilon.$$
Thus for arbitrary $\varepsilon>0$,$$
\mu\left(F\cap\bigcup_i A_i\right)+\mu\left(F\cap\left(\bigcup_i A_i\right)^c\right)\leq \mu(F)+\varepsilon.
$$Letting $\varepsilon$ tend to $0$ gives one the desired result.

Comment: Ooooh! It was so obvius, thanks.